# What Open Commerce API settings result in wide open access for a client-id?

Tags: commerce-cloud

When configuring [Open Commerce API settings](https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/18.3/usage/OCAPISettings.html?cp=0_12_2_22) is there a configuration that would provide read and write access to all resources?

Something like:

```
{
  "_v":"18.3",
  "clients":
  [
    {
      "allowed_origins":["http://www.sitegenesis.com","https://secure.sitegenesis.com"],
      "client_id":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "resources":
      [
        {
          "resource_id":"/*",
          "methods":["get","patch","delete","put"],
          "read_attributes":"(**)",
          "write_attributes":"(**)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this settings you get the full access to the desired resource and all sub-resources.

```
"resources": [
    {
      "resource_id": "/**",
      "methods": [
        "put",
        "get",
        "post",
        "patch"
      ],
      "read_attributes": "(**)",
      "write_attributes": "(**)"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please include explanation of why you should use these settings rather than just a code dump. See [answer] for how to write a good answer.